# MYSQL Autocommit when using multiple functions

Tags: php, mysql, transactions, autocommit

Will try to make this as simple as possible.  I'm using throw/catch with my functions.  The function takes in a name a description, and an array of users.  It adds the name and description to one table, then takes the array of users, and does a seperate function for adding them into a connector table.  I set the function up to turn autocommit off until the last user is entered and then commit.  The problem is that if one of the users fails to go in (due to a foreign key constraint), the transaction isn't backed out.  Does the fact that I'm calling a seperate function "reset" the autocommit and cause it to not work as intended?  Am I doing it wrong by putting the rollback in the Catch clause?

```
try
{
    autocommit=0
    run insert query
    if query fails: throw error, rollback
    else
      for count of array
        run another function (this function does more SQL and throws its own errors if it fails)

    autocommit=1
}

catch
{
    rollback, autocommit=1;
    display error
}
```

Hopefully I haven't oversimplified the code.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Update:  By moving the code that the other function runs into the main function, it works.  By that logic...calling another function resets the autocommit?

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->dbh->beginTransaction();
try {
    // do stuff

    $this->dbh->commit();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    $this->dbh->rollBack();
    throw $e;
}
```

Comment: That's essentially what I'm doing.  The difference is, in the 'try' statement, I have a call to another function that does more SQL.  That function will throw its own error when it bombs.  This function will get called several times in the try statement.  If one of those calls fails, I want the entire transaction to get rolled back, and it isn't.  I've thrown the 2 functions in question on a paste site.  Perhaps that will explain further: http://pastie.org/5553135